# Extract data from old Clié's Addressbook.pdb file

Tags: software-rec, palm

Does anyone know if there exists an utility to extract the data from a `AddressDB.pdb`**<sup>1</sup>** file (from a Clié, PalmOS).

I am primarily on a Windows 7 laptop, so solutions that work for Windows would be preferred, but are not necessarily required.

**<sup>1</sup>** I got the addressbook file from a backup of the PDA that I ran a while ago on my Linux desktop.

Comment: PDB files often tend to be plain text -  try opening it up in a text editor

Comment: There is recognizable text in the file, but it contains binary data as well. It's not really "simple" enough for me to guess what data is what to modify it into something like a CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [a Perl script that does what you want](http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AK/AKOLB/padb2csv). I used it myself back in the days when I had a PDA. It's old and I don't know if new Perl versions might have have broken it.

Comment: It does run, but it failed on some of the records.  Still, if there are no better answers I will consider yours good enough.